# Why is '\x' invalid in Python?

Tags: python, string, ascii, backslash, control-characters

I was experimenting with '\' characters, using '\a\b\c...' just to enumerate for myself which characters Python interprets as control characters, and to what.  Here's what I found:

```
\a - BELL
\b - BACKSPACE
\f - FORMFEED
\n - LINEFEED
\r - RETURN
\t - TAB
\v - VERTICAL TAB
```

Most of the other characters I tried, '\g', '\s', etc. just evaluate to the 2-character string of a backslash and the given character.  I understand this is intentional, and makes sense to me.

But '\x' is a problem.  When my script reaches this source line:

```
val = "\x"
```

I get:

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

What is so special about '\x'?  Why is it treated differently from the other non-escaped characters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a table listing all the escape codes and their meanings in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

```
Escape Sequence    Meaning                        Notes
\xhh               Character with hex value hh    (4,5)
```

> Notes:
>
> 4. Unlike in Standard C, exactly two hex digits are required.
>   5. In a string literal, hexadecimal and octal escapes denote the byte
>   with the given value; it is not necessary that the byte encodes a character
>   in the source character set. In a Unicode literal, these escapes denote a
>   Unicode character with the given value.

Answer (score 6):

`\xhh` is used to represent [hex escape characters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0223/).

Answer (score 6):

x is used to define (one byte) hexadecimal literals in strings, for example:

```
'\x61'
```

will evaluate to 'a', because 61 is the hexadecimal value of 97, which represents a in ASCII

Answer (score 4):

\x is missing the hex character you want to match against: \xnn -> \x1B

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving the full escape sequence:

> \xhh...
>
> The hexadecimal value hh, where hh stands for a sequence of
> hexadecimal digits (‘0’–‘9’, and either ‘A’–‘F’ or ‘a’–‘f’). Like the
> same construct in ISO C, the escape sequence continues until the first
> nonhexadecimal digit is seen. (c.e.) However, using more than two
> hexadecimal digits produces undefined results. (The ‘\x’ escape
> sequence is not allowed in POSIX awk.)

From: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html