# ValueError: invalid \x escape in this case

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is ‘\x’ invalid in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704654/why-is-x-invalid-in-python)

```
realId = 'Test'
id = ""
for x in realId:
 id += '\x'+str(ord(x))
print id
```

Honestly I'm pretty new to python and askii conversion so this should be a quick answer. I'm getting an error when creating this string, would anyone like to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah i read that but i couldn't find out how to create them during runtime

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> realId = 'Test'
>>> id = ""
>>> for x in realId:
...     id += r'\x'+str(ord(x))
... 
>>> print id
\x84\x101\x115\x116
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
realId = 'Test'
id = ""
for x in realId:
   id += r'\x%02x' % ord(x)
print id  # \x54\x65\x73\x74
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't possible, because `\x__` is a part of the string syntax, and cannot be done dynamically.  However, you can use `chr` to get the equivalent characters:

```
>>> chr(0x01)
'\x01'
>>> chr(0x41)
'A'
```