# Splitting string on several delimiters without considering new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, split

I have a string representing conversation turns as follows:

```
s = "person alpha:\nHow are you today?\n\nperson beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.\n\nperson alpha:\nWhat's up?\n\nperson beta:\nNot much, just hanging around."
```

In plain text, it looks as follows.

```
person alpha:
How are you today?

person beta:
I'm fine, thank you.

person alpha:
What's up?

person beta:
Not much, just hanging around.
```

Now, I would like to split the string on `person alpha` and `person beta`, so that the resulting list looks as follows:

["person alpha:\nHow are you today?", "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?", "person beta:\nNot much, just hanging around."]

I have tried the following approach

```
import re
res = re.split('person alpha |person beta |\*|\n', s)
```

But the results is as follows:

```
['person alpha:', 'How are you today?', '', 'person beta:', "I'm fine, thank you.", '', 'person alpha:', "What's up?", '', 'person beta:', 'Not much, just hanging around.']
```

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: I edited the question and other answers here to avoid [shadowing the built-in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125172/what-is-the-problem-with-shadowing-names-defined-in-outer-scopes) `str`, which can cause [all sorts of problems later on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605). In my experience, leaving things like that alone tends to distract other commenters and answerers, drawing attention away from the underlying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) will be the appropriate approach. Use `re.DOTALL` flag to match new lines. The `(alpha|beta)` in the regex is a group that matches either "alpha" or "beta", `.*?` is a non-greedy pattern that matches any characters and `(?=\n\nperson|$)` is a positive lookahead which asserts that the match is only successful if it immediately followed by a new line characters and person string

```py
import re

s = "person alpha:\nHow are you today?\n\nperson beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.\n\nperson alpha:\nWhat's up?\n\nperson beta:\nNot much, just hanging around."

match = re.findall(r"(person (alpha|beta):\n.*?(?=\n\nperson|$))", s, re.DOTALL)
result = list(map(lambda x: x[0], match ))
# or
# result = [x[0] for x in match]
print(result)
```

Ouput:

```
['person alpha:\nHow are you today?', "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?", 'person beta:\nNot much, just hanging around.']
```

To match **"person alpha:" and "Human:"** use the below regex:

```py
match = re.findall(r"((person alpha|Human):\n.*?(?=\n\n(person alpha|Human)|$))", s, re.DOTALL)
```

To match **both:** use the below regex:

```py
match = re.findall(r"((person|Human) (alpha|beta):\n.*?(?=\n\n(person|Human)|$))", s, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: I edited the answer to include another regex at the bottom of the previous answer

Answer (score 3):

> `'person alpha |person beta |\*|\n'`

There are multiple things wrong with this attempt. First off: the pattern passed to `re.split` is supposed to match the **delimiters**, not the items. That is, parts of the text that will **not** appear inside any of the items in the result list, but instead are in between:

```
>>> re.split('delimiter', 'foodelimiterbardelimiterbaz')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Aside from that, `person alpha` and `person beta` in the text are followed consistently by a colon, *not* a space; so those alternatives don't ever match. `\*` would match a literal asterisk (since it's escaped); but there's no apparent reason to look for that. `\n` **is** a literal newline in this regex; as it happens, Python's regex engine will accept a newline in the regex string and treat it as if it were backslash-n escape sequence - but it's important to understand in general that [there are two layers of escaping going on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/).

Anyway, the point is: this regex matches against a single newline in the input, and also matches some other possibilities that never come up. Then, `re.split` returns a list of things that are between those matches - i.e., the lines of the input.

---

> Now, I would like to split the string on person alpha and person beta, so that the resulting list looks as follows

Generally, we say "split on X" to mean that X is the delimiter. Since `person alpha` and `person beta` are both things that should appear at the beginnings of results, they are not delimiters.

Instead, the delimiter we are looking for is the **word boundary before** those phrases.

When we look for that delimiter, we want to make sure that it is followed by the person identifier (so that we know that it's the delimiter), but the regex needs to **not match** that identifer. To address this, we use positive lookahead.

We want: a word boundary (`\b`), with a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) for `person` , followed by one of the person names, followed by a colon. To simplify, I'll assume that the person name can be anything after the word `person`, and shouldn't be restricted to `alpha` and `beta`.

So the lookahead should match `person.*:`, meaning the entire lookahead clause is `(?=person.*:)`. The entire regex is `\b(?=person.*:)`, and we use a **raw string** for this, so that the backslash is understood literally by Python and passed literally to the regex engine (which will do its own interpretation of the `\b` sequence, [instead of Python's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704654)).

Putting it together:

```
>>> re.split(r'\b(?=person.*:)', s)
['', 'person alpha:\nHow are you today?\n\n', "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.\n\n", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?\n\n", 'person beta:\nNot much, just hanging around.']
```

---

Notice that that left an empty string at the beginning of the output list. That's because the delimiter that we're looking for is at the beginning of the input. `re.split` gives us whatever's before, between and after the delimiters. Before the first delimiter, in our case, is an empty string.

To avoid this, one simple approach is to recast the problem. Instead of searching for the points *between* the dialog items, we'll search for the dialog items themselves (it doesn't matter that there isn't any *text* in between them).

Each item looks like `person` , a name, `:`, whatever text, and two newlines - as a regex, `person.*?:.*?\n\n`. Because the regex will now actually match text rather than just looking ahead, it's important to use [reluctant qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840) - the `?`s in that regex.

Then, we use that regex with `re.findall`. It needs to use a raw string again, and we also need to use the `re.DOTALL` option for the regex, to tell the regex engine that `.` should be able to match a newline. (Otherwise, the regex would fail, because the second `.*?` won't match the single newlines within each dialog item before the double newline is reached.)

Putting it together:

```
>>> re.findall(r'person.*?:.*?\n\n', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
['person alpha:\nHow are you today?\n\n', "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.\n\n", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?\n\n"]
```

---

There are many other ways to write the regex, depending on *how the requirements are interpreted*. For example, rather than matching a word boundary (`\b`) with the `re.split` approach, we could look for a beginning-of-line anchor (`^`). In fact, we don't need anything besides the lookahead pattern, as long as we don't mind splitting the text *anywhere* that it says `person someone:` (even if it isn't at the beginning of a line (`^`), isn't at the beginning of a word (`\b`), or whatever else). With the `re.findall` approach, on the other hand, we could exclude the `\n\n` from the matches by checking for it with lookahead.

But if the items are always separated by `\n\n`, and it isn't really necessary to verify that they start with a person label, we could just split the text on that literal sequence. **That doesn't even require regex**:

```
>>> s.split('\n\n')
['person alpha:\nHow are you today?', "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?", 'person beta:\nNot much, just hanging around.']
```

Comment: Well, can you think of a regex that matches both of those things? Did you understand, in the original examples, which part matches that part of the data? If you try swapping that part of the regex, do you get the result you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern only matches a newline, as in the example data there is a colon : after `alpha:` and `beta:` so you are basically splitting on a newline yielding those results.

You could [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) the string using a lookahead `(?=` asserting instead of matching, and remove empty strings and strip the results.

```
import re

s = "person alpha:\nHow are you today?\n\nperson beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.\n\nperson alpha:\nWhat's up?\n\nperson beta:\nNot much, just hanging around."
pattern = r"(?=^person (?:alpha|beta):)"
res = [v.rstrip() for v in re.split(pattern, s, 0, re.M) if v]

print(res)
```

Output

```
['person alpha:\nHow are you today?', "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?", 'person beta:\nNot much, just hanging around.']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LOrB8d).

---

Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) you can match all lines with at least a single character asserting that the next line does not start with the person pattern:

```
import re

s = "person alpha:\nHow are you today?\n\nperson beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.\n\nperson alpha:\nWhat's up?\n\nperson beta:\nNot much, just hanging around."
pattern = r"^person (?:alpha|beta):\n(?:(?!person (?:alpha|beta):).+(?=\n|$))*"
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['person alpha:\nHow are you today?', "person beta:\nI'm fine, thank you.", "person alpha:\nWhat's up?", 'person beta:\nNot much, just hanging around.']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/73WWRB).

Comment: Compared to this answer, I tried to add more explanation and advice; but if the question were edited into its best possible form - i.e. *focused* as much as possible - this answer would probably be better suited overall.

Comment: @BlackHawk You can do that using an alternation `^(?:person alpha|Human):`